# Excel Data Connection Refresh - New Data to New Row Without Overwriting Previous

Tags: sql, vba, excel, data-extraction

I have an SQL data connection in Excel. It works perfectly, but what I would like is that when the data refreshes it moves to either a new worksheet or simply to the next empty row instead of overwriting the previous results from the query. This would allow me to create a simple archive for live, changing data.

I'm expecting a macro is required after much trawling of the net, it's clear that Excel doesn't have a direct answer for this.

Comment: Just a thought....you could create some VBA to just copy the updated data from the SQL data connection into the bottom of a "master" sheet instead of trying to move the connection itself.  This would likely be easier to do.